# Drupal 6: CAPTCHA on a custom form

Tags: drupal

How can I add CAPTCHA (version 6.x-2.0-rc3) to custom form in Drupal 6?

Is it just me or is it really difficult to find any good documentation on Drupal....

Comment: i think maybe its just you as there is tons of documentation on drupal. much of it is very good too. moreso than probably any other cms. where are you looking?

Comment: really I can do a search on Google or Drupal with the above terms and not find any helpful documents in the first 10 pages... seriously. Which is why I post so many Drupal questions here instead because its quicker! :)

Comment: I agree with EddyR, documention on some drupal integrations are sparse at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search in the [CAPTCHA](http://drupal.org/project/captcha) issues queue led me [here](http://drupal.org/node/473422#comment-1631234).

The key example code seems to be:

`$form['captcha'] = array(
  '#type' => 'captcha',
  '#captcha_type' => 'captcha/Math',
);`

There is also some good information in the module readmes.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by 'custom form' as there's many interpretations of those words ..

meanwhile did you find this 
[captcha/drupal video tutorial](http://blip.tv/file/361003/) ?

Comment: In a module using a form array. I figured you would be able to attach CAPTCHA simply by listing it in the array.